# How to save Note item modification

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am creating my Notes app using Core Data.

I am successfully creating New Notes using the following code:

```
let note = CoreDataHelper.newNote()
        note.noteTitle = noteTitleTextField.text ?? ""
        note.noteContent = noteContentTextView.text ?? ""
        note.noteDate = Date() as NSDate
        CoreDataHelper.saveNote()
```

However, how do I let the user save modifications on an existing note (vs. creating another new note)?

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your `Note` model class? You need a unique id for every object so that you would know if one instance of `Note` is new or not.

Comment: You have to fetch a note from coredata by uniquely identifying it via some property. And then make changes and save again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a sperate model for note (not managedObject type), What you can do is set the model and when user tries to save the modified data find and fetch the item (note) from coredata in required managedObjectContext with the help of id and then set the properties as modification on the fetched managedObject . Finally  managedObjectContext.save() will save all data as per modification. This approach will actually be helpful in the scenerios where user will cancel all the modification.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with existing notes, you would first fetch those notes from your managed object context. You're probably already doing this, if you're displaying existing notes in the app. Take whichever `Note` object you want to update and assign a new value to `note.noteContent`. Then save changes. Don't create a new note (as you do in the first line above)-- use one of the notes that you find in your fetch request results.